# Database design- Correct usage of many-to-many relationships between three tables?

Tags: sql, database-design, many-to-many, relationship

## Context

I have three tables, `Users`, `Subreddits`, and `Keywords`. The idea is that `users` can monitor multiple `subreddits`, and `subreddits` can keep track of multiple `keywords`.

Since one user can monitor multiple subreddits, and one subreddit can have multiple users monitoring it, I used a many-to-many relationship between `Users` and `Subreddits`.

On the same note, since one subreddit can keep track of multiple keywords, and one keyword can be tracked by multiple subreddits, I used a many-to-many relationship between `Subreddits` and `Keywords`.

## Implementation

The following is how I implemented each table, and their many-to-many-relationships:

#### Users

```
users_subreddits = db.Table('users_subreddits',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE')),
    db.Column('subreddit_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subreddits.id',  ondelete='CASCADE'))
)

class User(db.Model, JsonSerializer):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    phone_num = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    received_posts = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True, unique=True)

    subreddits = db.relationship('Subreddit', secondary=users_subreddits, backref='users', lazy='dynamic')

    //...
```

#### Subreddits

```
subreddits_keywords = db.Table('subreddits_keywords', db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column('subreddit_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subreddits.id', ondelete='CASCADE')),
    db.Column('keyword_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('keywords.id',  ondelete='CASCADE')),
)

class Subreddit(db.Model, JsonSerializer):
    __tablename__ = 'subreddits'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    subreddit_name = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)

    keywords = db.relationship('Keyword', secondary=subreddits_keywords, backref='subreddits', lazy='dynamic')

    // ...
```

#### Keywords

```
class Keyword(db.Model, JsonSerializer):
    """
    The keywords table.
    """

    __tablename__ = 'keywords'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    keyword = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)
```

## Problem

Since I want to keep track of how individual users are monitoring their subreddits and keywords, I append `Keywords` to `Subreddits`, and each Subreddit is appended to `Users`.

For example,

- `user1` monitors `subreddit1`, which is keeping track of `keyword1` and `keyword2`.
- `keyword1` and `keyword2` are appended to `subreddit1`.
- `subreddit1` is appended to `user1`.

Here is the problem. Since I am using many-to-many relationships, I would like to keep all data in each table unique. *Is this a bad idea?*

To illustrate what I mean, consider the following:

- `user1` monitors `subreddit1`, which is keeping track of `keyword1` and `keyword2`.
- `user2` monitors `subreddit1`, which is keeping track of `keyword3`.

Since `subreddit1` is unique in the database, `keyword1` and `keyword2` is appended to `subreddit1` by user1, but `keyword3` is also appended to `subreddit1` by user2.

That means `subreddit1` is keeping track of `keyword1`, `keyword2`, and `keyword3`. This is a problem when `user2` is only monitoring `keyword3` for `subreddit1`.

`Is a many-to-many relationship here a bad idea?`

## Solutions I've Considered

I can keep different instances of `subreddit1` for each user. And each of these `subreddit1` will keep track of their respective keywords.

The result will be:

- `user1` monitors `subreddit1`, which is keeping track of `keyword1` and `keyword2`.
- `user2` monitors `subreddit1`, which is keeping track of `keyword3`.

Since there are 2 `subreddit1`s, `user1`'s `subreddit1` is appended with `keyword1` and `keyword2`, while `user2`'s `subreddit1` is appended with `keyword3`.

`If I use this approach, what is the point of using a many-to-many relationship? Is there an alternative I can use?` I thought the point of a many-to-many relationship is so that each entry in `Subreddits` can relate to different users and different keywords, without the need to create duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your design effectively allows any combination of user, subreddit and keyword (nothing inherently wrong with that) then one solution would be to create a “monitoring” table that holds foreign keys to the 3 tables and records each allowable combination of user/subreddit/keyword. Effectively you are creating a many-to-many table that links 3 tables rather than just 2

Comment: I see, I will look more into this. Is there a name for this concept? For example, an association table is used to create a many-to-many relationship between two tables. Is there a name for a table that uses 3 foreign keys?

Comment: It’s still an association table regardless of the number of entities it is associating

Comment: I went along similar lines of using a a table with 3 foreign keys. However, since an association table is usually for two tables/foreign keys, I used an `association object` to contain 3 foreign keys.